Ag-Grid: When resizing the browser when using sizeColumnsToFit makes the pinned columns as scrollable
I am using the AG-Grid and when I use the SizeColumnsToFit, on resizing the browser the pinned group columns also get scrollable horizontallly. Is there a way to retain the pinned columns even when we resize the browser and then make it full screen.
I tried using the autoSIzeAllColumms and sizeColumnsToFit.

Could you provide some demo code? CodeSandbox makes it easy to create a demo.
